# Coloured Background to Show Active Navigation Page HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, background

I have a simple html menu that is styled using CSS.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="early.html">Growing Up and School</a></li>
        <li><a href="career.html">Films</a></li>
        <li><a href="jamesbond.html">James Bond</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I am looking for is a way to show the user what page is currently in use by way of a coloured background on the correct bit of the navigation menu. E.g. when the user is on the career page, the li box would be a different colour to the rest of the menu to show that it is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is add a class to whatever menu item is currently active. For example, the HTML markup for `index.html` would look like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="early.html">Growing Up and School</a></li>
        <li><a href="career.html">Films</a></li>
        <li><a href="jamesbond.html">James Bond</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the markup for `career.html` would look like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="early.html">Growing Up and School</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="career.html">Films</a></li>
        <li><a href="jamesbond.html">James Bond</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then style the class accordingly:

```
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done that and kind of got it working. The background to the active link is now a different colour like how I want it. However, the coloured background 'box' for the active link is in a different position when viewed in different browsers. It's in the perfect place when viewed in FF but in chrome and IE the box is overlapping the top or bottom of the menu if that makes sense. Is it to do with how i've styled my menu? This is my CSS:

Comment: #menu {
 max-width: 960px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 background-color: #d71900;
 border-top: 2px black solid;
}

#menu li {
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-right: 50px;
    padding: 12px 2px 6px 2px;
}

#menu ul {
 margin-top: 4px;
}

.activelink {
    background-color: #b01803;
}

a {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica;
 font-weight: normal ;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: @markthornton90 That appears to be a different question. I'd go ahead and create a new post describing your problem, you'll get better results that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an`'active'` class.

When you are on a certain page, you will add the `class="active"` to your link ( or li element ) . This is how wordpress and many other web application solve this.

Look here : http://jsfiddle.net/Bm9E4/2/

Comment: i just fixed it . sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

On the active page, add a class of `.active` to the LI for that page.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="early.html">Growing Up and School</a></li>
        <li><a href="career.html">Films</a></li>
        <li><a href="jamesbond.html">James Bond</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then do CSS for the background:

```
#main li.active { background-color:red; }
```